# Windows 10 v1709 RSAT missing DNS Manager

Tags: windows-10, windows-server-2016

In older versions of Windows, I was able to use DNS Manager inside MMC.  Is Windows 10 v1709 RSAT missing DNS Management?

EDIT : Don't understand the downvote.  A "Yes" is fine, and useful to anyone in the future who was also confused by the lack of functionality.  MS quietly took away the feature, it appears.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "Yes" is not the right answer. I've done DNS management from Windows 10 before, but I have had to do a bunch of random things similar to the current answer to get all the RSAT tools working, and the initial build of Windows 10 didn't support all the tools. The last build I was working did support all the tools, IIRC. I'm stuck back on Windows 7 at this time.

Answer (score 3):

The [RSAT for Windows 10 Download Page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520) seems to have diverged into 2 different releases of RSAT for Windows 10: `WS_1709 RSAT` and `WS2016 RSAT`. The WS2016 version is for managing the originally released version of Windows Server 2016 and any earlier versions. The WS1709 version is explicitly for managing the new semi-annual release channel of Windows Server currently known as Windows Server 1709. Here's a [Microsoft article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/get-started-with-1709) that goes into more detail about that release.

In any case, the RSAT download page has a set of known issues in the Additional Information section of the page. One of them is *DNS Tools Missing* on the WS 1709 version. Their solution is to either switch to using the WS2016 version or use the workaround specified in [KB4055558](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4055558/rsat-missing-dns-server-tool-in-windows-10-version-1709) which is a more detailed version of the answer that @magicandre1981 posted and basically involves uninstalling the package, creating a modified unattend file, and re-installing the package with the custom file.

Answer (score 0):

copy the [MSU of RSAT](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520) and extract the ZIP for your CPU architecture ([32Bit](https://www.windows-faq.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/unattend_x86.zip), [64Bit](https://www.windows-faq.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/unattend_x64.zip)) into `C:\temp`.

Now open a cmd.exe as admin in C:\Temp and run `installx64.bat` for 64Bit or `installx32.bat` for 32Bit Windows:

[image]

This [install RSAT + DNS Manager](https://www.windows-faq.de/2018/01/03/rsat-tools-windows-10-fall-creators-1709-kb2693643-dns-manager/)

Comment: Is there a method actually sanctioned by Microsoft?  Like their removal of Disk Cleanup from Windows Server, there may be functionality reasons, like avoiding deletion of critical files.

Comment: I just read this blog post a few days ago and remembered it. I personally don't use RSAT. Test if it works.